# Apache 404 FilesMatch

Tags: php, docker, apache, httpd.conf

Considering the following working Apache config (used inside the httpd:2.4.48-alpine docker container)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   
   DocumentRoot "/code2"

   <Proxy "fcgi://php/">
       ProxySet enablereuse=On
   </Proxy>

   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
   </FilesMatch>

   <Directory /code2>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>

   DirectoryIndex index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

However if I move the /code2 directory which matches the path in the php-fpm container (named "php") to e.g: /code ( I also update the DocumentRoot and Directory path ).

I get a 404 on all the php files. Why is this so? how can I provide a different path to the php files for each container?

Another interesting thing to note is that both the access log of apache and php don't display the full path to the php file thats being accessed, just the filename only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the "DocumentRoot" directive with a PHP handler, you need to mount that volume to `httpd` as well. By default, non-existent files will directly trigger a 404 (See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP-FPM "Proxy via handler")

Here's a small example (with docker-compose for simplicity) for your use-case:

`./docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  httpd:
    build:
      context: ./httpd/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./php-vol:/code2:rw
  php:
    image: php:8.0-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./php-vol:/code2:rw
      - ./php-vol2:/code2/another-dir:rw
```

`./httpd/Dockerfile`

```
FROM httpd:2.4.48-alpine

COPY php-fpm.conf conf/extra/php-fpm.conf

RUN echo "Include conf/extra/php-fpm.conf" >> conf/httpd.conf

RUN sed -i \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_proxy.so\)/\1/' \
        -e 's/^#\(LoadModule .*mod_proxy_fcgi.so\)/\1/' \
        conf/httpd.conf
```

`./httpd/php-fpm.conf` (using PHP handler, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP-FPM)

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/code2"

   <Proxy "fcgi://php/">
       ProxySet enablereuse=On
   </Proxy>

   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
   </FilesMatch>
   
   <Directory /code2>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>

   DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

If you only want to serve .php files with `php-fpm`, this could be simplified:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/code2/$1

   DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So the answer to your question "how can I provide a different path to the php files for each container?" is: You can't have different paths between php-fpm and httpd.

Comment: This is similar to the working example I provided, I am providing a DocumentRoot for non php files. I want the paths to be different as this would allow for a generic container instead of multiple copies. I don't see any functional difference to my working example so I don't regard this as an answer. I would like to mount the files in a different location. With nginx I provide a relative path and prefix it with a different root. With apache this should be default?

Comment: If it's not possible as you stated however that's a valid answer. Are you sure? DirectoryPath is not useful?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the DocumentRoot Apache vs. php-fpm must be equal if you want want static files served directly by Apache.
I added another PHP-volume to the example above, mounting it somewhere inside the DocumentRoot - maybe that serves your use case better? 
The next thing you could look into would be an additional php-fpm pool, but that requires another Apache VirtualHost (with another DocumentRoot), of course.

Comment: Can you maybe add a more complete example of which URL paths you expect to be served from which volume and by which service (apache/php-fpm)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a different path in httpd and php-fpm you can customize the environment variables sent to php-fpm with ProxyFCGISetEnvIf.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#proxyfcgisetenvif

Unfortunately the combination of variables php-fpm might look at to determine where to look on disk can be a little confusing -- it's actually the reason this directive exists to give you a chance at the last moment to see what mod_proxy_fcgi would have sent and then tweak them.

This example from the manual is eerily (with the \d suffix being dropped) close to your issue:

```
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "reqenv('PATH_TRANSLATED') =~ m|(/.*prefix)(\d+)(.*)|" PATH_TRANSLATED "$1$3"
```

I suggest using this pattern to transform PATH_TRANSLATED (filesystem path) from your httpd container to the one that's valid in the FPM container.

Comment: the last time I looked at this (probably to implement ProxyFCGISetEnvIf) I found this fake FPM server that dumps the variables useful: https://hastebin.com/xexexomubi.php